# discord.py | check for 2 or more messages

Tags: python, discord.py

I tried to program a discord bot that checks several messages one after the other.
So if someone writes "Hello", the bot should write "Hello there" and check whether the following message "How are you?" is.

```
    @client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'hi' in message.content:
        await message.channel.send('Hello there.')
        if 'How are you?' in message.content:
            await message.channel.send('I am fine.')
```

But the bot ignores the second command. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete this article and to help others I am posting the correct and finished code in here.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('Hi'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Hello!')

        def check(message1):
            return message1.content == 'How are you?' and message1.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send("I am fine.".format(msg))
```

I hope this article helps some other people! Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

When writing it like that, it checks if there is a How are you in the message where there was a hi. To make your bot respond and then wait for a response use `wait_for`

It would look like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'hi' in message.content:
        await message.channel.send('Hello there.')
        await bot.wait_for("How are you", check=check)
```

What this is doing, is if a message has hi in it, the bot responds, and then waits for a message with How are you

Comment: The bot is waiting, but it can't answer on the question How are you.
How should I do this?

Comment: on the line after await you would write ctx.send("great hbu")

Answer (score 0):

The second message you send will again passes as message to on_message() function.
try this

```
async def on_message(message):
    if 'hi' in message.content:
        await message.channel.send('Hello there.')
    if 'How are you?' in message.content:
        await message.channel.send('I am fine.')
```